# SQL - specific grouping/counting (avoid cursors)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make specific grouping/counting with out cursors.
I know that is possible to made this with cursors, but I am trying to avoid that.
My table looks like this:

```
ID | Amount
1  | 1200
2  | 1200
3  | 2500
5  | 1200
6  | 1200
7  | 1200
8  | 2500
```

Result should be

```
Count| Amount
2    | 1200
1    | 2500
3    | 1200
1    | 2500
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih DBMS is mssql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, basically, a *gaps and islands* situation.

- data is stored in the `TEST` table
- `INTER` CTE selects *previous* row's `AMOUNT` value, using the `LAG` analytic function
- `INTER2` CTE creates groups (using `SUM` analytic function)
- the final query counts rows per amount, grouped by the group (`GRP` column). I included `MIN(RN)`, just to set the correct ordering. You can remove it.

.

```
with 
inter as
  (select rn, amount, 
     isnull(lag(amount) over (order by rn), amount) l_amount
   from test
  ),
inter2 as
  (select rn, amount,
     sum(case when amount <> l_amount then 1 else 0 end) over (order by rn) grp
   from inter
  )
select min(rn) rn, amount, count(*) cnt
from inter2
group by amount, grp
order by 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle is here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/006fb/12)

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  I would solve this version using the difference of row numbers:

```
select amount, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by amount order by id) as seqnum_a
      from t
     ) t
group by amount, (seqnum - seqnum_a);
```

Why this works is not generally obvious the first time you see it.  The goal is to assign a group to the adjacent elements with the same amount.

If you stare at the results of the subquery, you'll see how the difference between these two sequences is constant when the amounts are the same and adjacent.  The rest is just aggregation.

If you know that the `id`s have no gaps, then you can use `id` instead of `seqnum`.